# How to test if a screen is the same by accessing it through two different ways using Jest in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-router

FYI, I'm pretty new to unit testing with React.

I'm not sure if this makes much sense but I'm being asked to make a Jest script using React, to ensure that a screen looks the same if being accessed through a button or by copy/pasting the direct link.

The onClick method that's triggered when button is pressed is as following:

```js
  const handleOnClick = (rowId) => {
      `/details/${folderId}/${rowId}`,
    );
  };
```

The React component that is rendered in that URL has a table that displays values taken as prop like this:

```js
type Props = {
  isLoading: boolean;
  isSuccess: boolean;
  prod1: Object;
  prod2?: Object;
  name1?: string;
  name2?: string;
};
```

The prod Object looks like this:

```js
Prod: {
  kpi1: number,
  kpi2: number,
  kpi3: number
}
```

Comment: React-Router content is based on matching the URL, it doesn't matter what set/updated the URL or how it did it. The only valuable test I see here is that the content is correct for a giving URL path.

Comment: @DrewReese I manually tested this, copy/pasting the URL does produce the same screen with same table information. The only thing I want to do is replicate that in Jest

Comment: If you are new to jest and unit testing in general it may be a good idea to narrow your scope of testing at first to understand how to write a simple test. Have a look at [the jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/tutorial-react#dom-testing).

Looking at the code in question, the `handleOnClick` function has syntax errors and only returns a string (or tries to) I am surprised that works at all. Is that all of the code?

Comment: Jest is a non-DOM environment, so I don't think you'll be able to write a unit test that replicates a user copy/pasting a URL into the address bar. This would be more akin to an integration test suite running against actual browsers, e.g. puppeteer, cypress, selenium/appium, etc.

Comment: @segFault Absolutely no need to be rude. Obviously my code has more things but are irrelevant to the question. Thanks for the help